# SDTT error for FAQ: "The property interactionType is not recognized by Google for an object of type CreativeWork."

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I am adding a FAQ Schema.org markup in my WordPress post and got an error message when testing it with Google Structured Data Testing Tool:

> The property `interactionType` is not recognized by Google for an object of type `CreativeWork`.

How do I solve this?

I expect the result to return @type FAQ.

Comment: Hi Vanblitz. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please give some additional information and add some tags (wordpress, maybe?) so the appropriate people see your question and can answer it.

Comment: Schema.org has no type named `FAQ`. Do you mean `FAQPage`?